# What does the 'class' function mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface Soka : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name;
-(void)speak;
@end

@implementation Soka
-(void)speak{
    NSLog(@"my name is: %@", self.name);
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString * asdfasdfasdfsdf = @"xxxxxxx4";
        id cls = [Soka class];
        void * obj = &cls;
        [(__bridge id)obj speak];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
[14402:5468392] my name is: xxxxxxx4
```

Can anyone explain this??

How was the asdfasdfasdfsdf values set to class property?

Thanks

---

### Thanks for all your guys' replies:

Making An Update:
@Leo

Thanks for your reply.

**1#** What is the meaning of **Soka Class object cls**, what is its memory structure. It's pointer pointing to what address?

**2#** find memory near the ocObj object? what if the nearest memory is an integer value? It's a part of OBJC or whatelse theory?

Comment: @CoryKramer no, it's objectC in xcode.

Comment: I don't see how that code produces that output.  No instance is created and `name` is not initialized.

Comment: @zaph OK, so it's using the stack to layout an fake-instance of `Soka`.  Interesting, but not very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Well it is a little tricky,not useful. It is about Objective C instance memory

Your code can be converted to this

```
    NSString * asdfasdfasdfsdf = @"xxxxxxx4";
    Class cls = [Soka class]; 
    void * obj = &cls; 
    id ocObj = (__bridge id)obj;
    NSLog(@"%@",[ocObj name]);
```

Lets make it clear one by one

1. cls is a Soka Class object

   ```
   Class cls = [Soka class];
   ```
2. obj is a pointer point to Soka Class object

   ```
   void * obj = &cls;
   ```
3. This convert obj to Object C object

   ```
   id ocObj = (__bridge id)obj;
   ```
4. When call this `[ocObj name]`,Objective C will find memory near the ocObj object.It is `@"xxxxxxx4"` in the stack.

Also,I test this to make sure I am right

```
@interface Soka : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString * address;
-(void)speak;
@end

@implementation Soka
-(void)speak{
    NSLog(@"my name is: %@", self.name);
}
@end

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSString * asdfasdfasdfsdf = @"xxxxxxx4";
    NSString * address = @"address";
    Class cls = [Soka class];
    void * obj = &cls;
    id ocObj = (__bridge id)obj;
    NSLog(@"%@",[ocObj name]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[ocObj address]);
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,    NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
 }
```

This will log

```
2015-07-01 23:26:56.857 OCTest[10910:347815] address
2015-07-01 23:26:56.859 OCTest[10910:347815] xxxxxxx4
```

**Update:**

`+class` function will return the class object of one class and type is `Class`.

So,what is `Class` type,it is something about objective c runtime

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

This is the define of objc_class

```
struct objc_class {
Class isa  OBJC_ISA_AVAILABILITY;

#if !__OBJC2__
Class super_class                                        OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
const char *name                                         OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
long version                                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
long info                                                OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
long instance_size                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_ivar_list *ivars                             OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_method_list **methodLists                    OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_cache *cache                                 OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
struct objc_protocol_list *protocols                     OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
#endif

} OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

When you create an Objective C object,it will auto manage the memory. In your code,it is just a trick to make an Objective C object like memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1# What is the meaning of **Soka Class object** __cls__, what is its memory structure. It's pointer pointing to what address? 
2# find memory near the ocObj object? what if the nearest memory is an integer value? It's a part of OBJC or whatelse theory?

Comment: `Class` is  a type in objective C.Wait a second,I will update my answer to make it clear

Comment: +class function will return the class object of one class and type is Class, 
So where does the cls point? a new mallocked memory?

Comment: `[Soka class]`,in your code,this will create a new memory in stack. cls point to this area

Answer (score 1):

Actually objective-c's classes is structures with properties.
For your's class `Soka` you have hidden fields in that structure: `_name` and `class`. They placed in same order, as placed your's variables `asdfasdfasdfsdf` and `cls`.

All works fine because at address `&cls` placed variable of type `Class`, that describes class. So after casting `obj` to `id` runtime find required field, that describes class and trust that that pointer points at `Soka`. Of course it'f false, but by circumstances that variables placed at same order and at right places this code work and doesn't crush.

You can't alloc objective-c objects in stack and should avoid this code if you think that you can alloc objective-c object in such way. Because it can lead to unpredicted errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` method gives you the type of an object.

For example, if you want to know if `myObject` is an `NSString`, you could do this:

```
[myObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
```

`isKindOfClass` takes a type as its argument, so we call `class` on `NSString` to get the type.

It's like `typeof` in the C languages.

Comment: Downvoted. Your answer is meaningless in the context of this question. Though author should have given a better title for it.